# Sessions or cookies does not get cleared while using localStorage.clear(); or sessionStorage.clear(); for protractor cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

in After hooks in cucumber, I am using the deleteAllCookies(), localStorage.clear() and sessionStorage.clear() but when I retrieve the session ID, expectation is that I should receive "no session or cookies" but still localStorage.clear() and sessionStorage.clear() does not delete local storage session or any cookies? any advice would be helpful

Comment: You are executing similar commands browser.executeScript(“localStorage.clear();”)??

Answer (score 0):

Below commands to clear local storage and session storage worked for me

```
 browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
 browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
```